# How to sort a queryset of different models in Wagtail/Django?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have a Wagtail site and I'm making a listing page for a few different Page types/Content types. I filter by a snippet field first:

```py
def highlights_list(category='Highlight'):
    tag = ContentCategory.objects.get(name=category)
    highlights = Page.objects.filter(
        Q(event__categories=tag)|
        Q(newspage__categories=tag)|
        Q(contentpage__categories=tag)).live()
    return highlights.order_by('-last_published_at')
```

In Wagtail all content types inherit from the base `Page` class which makes creating a queryset with all the content types I want really easy. But I can't work out how to sort nicely.

Sorting by `last_published_at` is fine for `NewsPage` and `ContentPage` but not for `Event` where I'd like to sort by the `DateTimeField` for the event.

I thought about making a `@property` on all the models called `sort_date` which uses the datetime field specific to each model that I'd like to sort on, but that just doesn't work.

Any suggestions are very welcome!

Comment: How did you set up your models.py?

Comment: Could you be more specific? I set all content types to subclass `wagtail.core.models.Page`, so they all have `last_published_at` available as a field via `ForeignKey`.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but specifically I meant to ask you if you would like to post your relevant models.py code in any way you prefer, please. For example, I want to know if Event and NewsPage are subclasses of Content Page.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. They both inherit from `Page`. I've put them in Dpaste but can edit the question if thats better for the long term - https://dpaste.org/DLTW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two solutions for this, but only one seems to be easier to do. I changed your function above to this:

```python
def highlights_list(category='Highlight'):
    tag = ContentCategory.objects.get(name=category)
    highlights = Page.objects.filter(
        Q(event__categories=tag)|
        Q(newspage__categories=tag)|
        Q(contentpage__categories=tag)
    ).live().specific()

    return sorted(
        highlights,
        key=lambda p: getattr(p, 'date') or getattr(p, 'last_published_at'),
        reverse=True
    )
```

What this does is it takes all the pages from `highlights` and sorts them based on the value in `date` or `last_published_at` as if they're the same field. Because only the `Event` page has a `date` field, `last_published_at` is used as the fallback, a field all live pages have in common. If you leave out `specific()` in your queryset like in your question, it throws an `AttributeError` saying `'Page' object has no attribute 'date'`.

As a bonus, the sorting part doesn't use any database queries since it is done in Python. Note that this returns a list based on the original `QuerySet`.

The second solution involves database transactions and Wagtail hooks and has more code, but that is something I don't want to share as I haven't thought of how to write that out.

Comment: This is almost perfect. I actually needed to do change the `lambda` to be `key=lambda p: getattr(p, 'date', None) or getattr(p, 'last_published_at')` to avoid exceptions. Thank you!